# Not able to get organization form node in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and not able to get organization from node.

File: pickerresults.lib.js
Method: createPersonResult(node)

```
function createPersonResult(node)
{
   var personObject = 
   {
      typeShort: node.typeShort,
      isContainer: false,
      properties: {},
      displayPath: node.displayPath,
      nodeRef: "" + node.nodeRef
   }

   // define properties for person
   personObject.properties.userName = node.properties.userName;

   // defining new property for the personObject but
   // but not getting any value
   personObject.properties.companyname = (node.properties["cm:organization"] ? node.properties["cm:organization"]  : "");
      personObject.properties.companyname = (node.properties.organization ? node.properties.organization : "");

   return personObject;
}
```

Override the pickerresults.lib.js file by copying it to location as below.

```
/Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.js
```

how could I get organization name? 
also how could I debug the node properties like logger.log is there but does not work here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to get properties without extra `"."` in

`node.properties.["cm:organization"]`

like:

```
node.properties["cm:organization"]
```

please refer this doc link 
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html

**properties**

Provides access to all the properties of this node. The properties returned are accessed via an associative array. Properties of a node can be accessed in the following ways:

Example: `node.properties["name"]`

Example: `node.properties.name`

example i have tried:

```
var node =people.getPerson("admin");
logger.log(node.properties["cm:email"]);
logger.log(node.properties.email);
```

Comment: I fixed this but I'm not able to override the pickerresults.lib.js file. I have updated my query. Please have a look at it.